# Making a string in a loop

Tags: java, string, loops

I want to make a string with the numbers of fields that I have, in this example 15 but I want a variable number of fields.

```
new String[] { "field1", "field2", "field3"}
```

I think a for would be a good idea but how can I sum the past "fields"?

```
String fields[];
    for (int i=0; i < headers.size(); i++){
         String temp[]={"field"+"[i]"}; 
         fields=fields+temp;
    }
```

What I want is

```
 String new[]{ "field1", "field2", "field3"}
```

Comment: Do you want to make a String array `String[]` or a single `String`?

Comment: What do you mean by *sum the past "fields"*? Post example of input and expected result. BTW arrays and list are indexed from 0, not 1.

Comment: @Pshemo I want to the String to contain all the fields in the loop

Comment: And how should result look like? If input will contain fields like `foo` `bar` then result should be `foobar` or `foo,bar` or `field1=foo, field2=bar` or maybe even something else?

Comment: foo, bar like in the String example

Comment: I am confused. Your response to Codebender comment was that you want to make "String array []" but you responded to my comment saying that you want String. So which is it, String array or String (they are not the same). To make this clearer post simple example (not necessary with 15 fields, but lets say with 3) and show us what result you expect (and maybe why).

Comment: Question is not clear please ask properly

Comment: What's the expected result ? Is it: "field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12 field13 field14 field15" ??

Comment: @JFPicard that's right

Comment: "*What I want is `String new[]{ "field1", "field2", "field3"}`*" if that is the output, then what is the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = 100;//The number you want
String[] tmp = new String[x];
for(int p = 0; p < x; p++) {
    tmp[p] = "field" + (p + 1); //P+1 to offset for the 0 start.
}
```

This will give what I think you are looking for as a result. Rather then what you were trying to do, simply create an empty array of the correct size, and then fill it with results.

If you are simply looking to print a summary of the fields, use something similar to this...

```
String output = "";
for(int p = 0; p < tmp.length; p++) {
    output += " " + tmp[p]; //added a space for readability
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: `output += " " + tmp[p];` never do that inside loop. Use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method. For now in each iteration you are creating new String which needs to copy old string and append new part to it. Notice that copying long string just to add some small part can be quite expensive.

Comment: I don't recommend to use a string concatenation in a loop. The best method is to use a StringBuilder to not clutter the memory with unecessary strings.

Comment: @JFPicard so something like this?  `for (int i=0; i < headers.size(); i++){
      String fields[] = new StringBuilder("fields" + i).toString();
     }`